# why can't I run em-websocket-server on JRuby?

Tags: jruby, em-websocket

I'm running JRuby-1.7.3 through rvm. I've successfully installed the *em-websocket-server* gem. I can verify it's in my current gemset by running *$ gem list*.

My code is this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'em-websocket-server'

class EchoServer < EM::WebSocket::Server

  def on_connect
    EM::WebSocket::Log.debug "Connected"
  end

  def on_receive msg
    send_message msg
  end

end

EM.run do
    EM.start_server "0.0.0.0", 8000, EchoServer
end
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

> LoadError: no such file to load -- em-websocket-server   require at
>   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027   require at
>   /home/dev1/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error because I was using the gem command directly instead of the jruby gem command.

To fix this just run:

```
jruby -S gem install em-websocket
```

This worked for me,  hope this helps you too.

Comment: thanks for reply, tried it but it didn't work. I can already verify that the gem is installed correctly and is in the right directory. It just doesn't get picked up by JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually solved itself after I removed rvm (`$ rvm implode`) and re-installed it

```
$ rvm get head --autolibs=3 # get the latest RVM and build required libs
$ rvm requirements # just in case, install all other required stuff
$ rvm install jruby
```

I then installed all my gems in the default gemset. *em-websocket-server* was then picked up and worked fine. I can only attribute this to some twisted configuration or even bug in my original rvm setup.